# Playing Civ 5, no sound

Tags: sound, 16.04, xubuntu, pulseaudio, alsa

On Xubuntu 16.04, trying to run Civ 5, I get no audio. When running through the terminal, I get this, among other things.

`AL lib: oss.c:169: Could not open /dev/dsp: No such file or directory`

How can I fix this?

Comment: For Arch users, install `lib32-alsa-oss`.

Answer (score 2):

installing the `libopenal1:i386` should help ; at least it did work on my station.

You need to open a terminal (`ctrl` + `alt` + `t`) and then type :

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
sudo apt-get install libopenal1:i386
```